# Need help looping though 3 loops to append data in Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working with Col A, B & C. Col A contains A-E, Col B Contains 1, a, 3, b, 5 and Col C will be where I will store duplicated information (a and b would go into C1 & C2). Any help would be appreciated.  In summary; compare A and B for similarity, output result into C

```
function appendString() {
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:A5");
    var range2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B1:B5");
    var range3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C1:C5")
    var numRows = range.getNumRows();
    var x = 0


    // var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
    j = 1 // row A
    k = 2 // row B
    m = 3 // row C
    n = 1
    // First loop though B
    for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
        // set the current value...
        var currentValue = range.getCell(i, j).getValue();
        // In the log tell us the current value
        Logger.log("Set A:" + currentValue);
        // Loops though col B to compare to col A
        for (var l = 1; l <= numRows; l++) {
            // Sets the current value to compare value
            var compareValue = range2.getCell(l, j).getValue();
            Logger.log("Set B:" + compareValue)
            // If the compareValue and the currentValue (match)
            if (compareValue === currentValue) {
                Logger.log("MATCHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH");
                // We will write the result to col C down one row
                for (n; n <= x; n++) {
                    // this makes it only run once'
                    range3.setValue(currentValue);
                    Logger.log("Appending.................");
                    x = n + 3
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem statement boils down to this: Fill column C with a list of unique values that appear in both column A and B.

There is a built-in javascript Array method `Array.indexOf()` that makes it very easy to search for matching elements. As the problem is defined, we want to search in a column, so to use that method we need a column to be represented as an Array. The `Range.getValues()` method allows us to load a whole range of values at once, and delivers them as a two-dimensional array, with rows as the first dimension. We need columns there, and we can achieve that by a matrix transposition.

So here's what we end up with. There isn't a built-in `transpose()`, so I've included one. As we search for matches, results are stored in an Array `C`, using the built-in `Array.push()` method. Finally, array `C` is treated as a two-dimensional array, transposed, and written out to the sheet in column C.

```
function recordMatches() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:B5");
  var data = range.getValues();

  // For convenience, we'll transpose the data, so
  // we can treat columns as javascript arrays.
  var transposed = transpose(data);
  var A = transposed[0],
      B = transposed[1],
      C = [];

  // Go through A, looking for matches in B - if found, add match to C
  for (var i=0; i < A.length; i++) {
    if (B.indexOf(A[i]) !== -1) C.push(A[i]);
  }

  // If any matches were found, write the resulting array to column C
  if (C.length > 0) {
    var rangeC = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,3,C.length);
    rangeC.setValues(transpose([C]));
  }
}

function transpose(a) {
  return Object.keys(a[0]).map(function (c) { return a.map(function (r) { return r[c]; }); });
}
```

Comment: This works very well thank you! Only problem I have seen is it is case sensitive,  "A" != "a", is there anyway to make it so "A" === "a" ???

Comment: no numbers or dates but i cant call toLoweCase on a range, im assuming i have to convert the range to an array of strings?

Comment: Thank you for being extremely helpful! I will read on how to accept answers after I finish the dishes ~__~